# How to add data to txt file in C?

Tags: c, file, getlasterror

in a C program I want to append data to a text file. Used the fopen function like this:

```
FILE* fileLog;
char logFile_name[] = "C:\\pg\\log.txt";
fileLog = fopen(logFile_name, "r+");
int j = 0;
while (j < 4)
{
    fprintf(fileLog, "%u,%s", GetLastError(), "1_aba_1\n");
    j++;
}
```

GetLastError sometimes returns (ok), but the file is overwritten and not added.

Used the fopen function like this:

```
FILE* fileLog;
char logFile_name[] = "C:\\pg\\log.txt";
fileLog = fopen(logFile_name, "a+");
std::cout << GetLastError() << " LOG \n";

int j = 0;
while (j < 3)
{
    fprintf(fileLog, "%u,%s", GetLastError(), "56_aba_4\n");
    j++;
}
```

Data is added but GetLastErrorgives an error 183.
Programm continues work correctly in both cases, but i use this code in postgre extension, and it crashes and lose connection server for unknown reasons. How to correctly add data to a file without error?

Comment: If you don't have an error in the last function, is `GetLastError()` meaningful? Does `fopen()` set a win32 error on Windows?

Comment: You should check if `fopen()` succeeded by checking to see if the pointer it returns is null.

Comment: I think because of the `GetLastError()`, the extension is falling, because the `GetLastError()` still returns some kind of error

Comment: @SovaKefirov you cannot mix `fopen` etc. and `GetLastError()`. Also the error number returned by `GetLastError()` is only set by WINAPI functions that are documented to set it and only if the said WINAPI function fails.

Comment: Why are you mixing C++ and C?

Comment: in question I do this for simplicity

Comment: You need only open in `"a"` (append) mode and then you need to check that `fopen()` succeeded before attempting to write to the file, e.g. `if (!fileLog) { perror ("fopen-fileLog"); return 1; }`

Comment: thank you, David, it helped

Comment: C++ and C do not mix too well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to work as a PostgreSQL extension you should  try to use the routines already available in PostgreSQL code that you can find in  postgres/src/include/storage/fd.h:

```
/*
 * calls:
 *
 *  File {Close, Read, Write, Size, Sync}
 *  {Path Name Open, Allocate, Free} File
 *
 * These are NOT JUST RENAMINGS OF THE UNIX ROUTINES.
 * Use them for all file activity...
 *
 *  File fd;
 *  fd = PathNameOpenFile("foo", O_RDONLY);
 *
 *  AllocateFile();
 *  FreeFile();
 *
 * Use AllocateFile, not fopen, if you need a stdio file (FILE*); then
 * use FreeFile, not fclose, to close it.  AVOID using stdio for files
 * that you intend to hold open for any length of time, since there is
 * no way for them to share kernel file descriptors with other files.
 *
 * Likewise, use AllocateDir/FreeDir, not opendir/closedir, to allocate
 * open directories (DIR*), and OpenTransientFile/CloseTransientFile for an
 * unbuffered file descriptor.
 *
 * If you really can't use any of the above, at least call AcquireExternalFD
 * or ReserveExternalFD to report any file descriptors that are held for any
 * length of time.  Failure to do so risks unnecessary EMFILE errors.
 */
```

This code is available on Linux and Windows.

You can find examples in pg_stat_statements extension source code:
postgres/contrib/pg_stat_statements/pg_stat_statements.c

Comment: where can i see explanation of arguments in these functions? i saw https://doxygen.postgresql.org/ and browse internet, but could not find good example or detailed information

Comment: AFAIK most of the documentation is actually the source code itself: sometimes functions have a commented header, sometimes not, sometimes there is a README file but above all you have all the source code: the functions source code itself and you can also check others parts of the code that are calling these routines. And if you don't know you can search or ask in the PG mailing lists https://www.postgresql.org/list/.

Answer (score 0):

from [Microsoft System Error Codes:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)

*ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS
183 (0xB7).
Cannot create a file when that file already exists*

I think that this is just a reminder that the file is already there.

Comment: I need the file to exist and I appended to it or read from it